# getattproperties: 70th attribute tuple from City_fact (relid=27835515) relation of DWA(dbid=296643) database not found

Tags: netezza

I am using Netezza system where nps version is 7.2.0.6. I am trying to run a query on a view which is created on base table City_fact. 
But getting above error.
Can someone please let me know in which scenario we get above error. I tried to find but was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in Netezza after migrating from TWINFIN to MAKO version. Drop and recreating the view worked in my case. Not sure this will help . but a suggestion if any faced similar issue.

Regards,
Bharani Raj

Answer (score 0):

This error was encounter when any base object id got changed (by alter table) which is used in any view, and that is not reflected in the view. in such case you need to refresh the view (Create or replace view)